# how can align statements on kotlin in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, reformatting

how can I align statements as follows:

```
const val KEY_UPLOAD_NATIONAL_CARD_1 = "national_card_page_1_img_url"
const val KEY_UPLOAD_NATIONAL_CARD_2 = "national_card_page_2_img_url"
const val KEY_UPLOAD_PROFILE_PIC     = "profile_pic_url"
```

instead of:

```
const val KEY_UPLOAD_NATIONAL_CARD_1 = "national_card_page_1_img_url"
const val KEY_UPLOAD_NATIONAL_CARD_2 = "national_card_page_2_img_url"
const val KEY_UPLOAD_PROFILE_PIC = "profile_pic_url"
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformat Code... (Ctrl+Alt+L / Cmd+Alt+L) It works not only for Kotlin Android Studio but also for any language supported by the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't.

Aside from the "Reformat Code" shortcut that @Muhammad Ammar already answered, there are no options to align special lines of code to a special char or a special line column.

How would the IDE know which lines to include? How would the IDE know which character or line to choose that it should align to? Of course, it could be implemented somehow, but this is such a specific feature that I doubt it will ever come.

Maybe you are lucky and there exists a plugin or you could roll up your sleeves and implement such a plugin yourself.

Comment: There is an option for Java that works very well called "Group declarations", and the same feature has been requested for Kotlin for at least 2 years now, but so far no signs of ever being implemented.